# How should I implement this?

Tags: java, file, parsing

I have 75+ different text files containing some lines of dialogue spoken by characters in a game. The text files have special commands that the game parses to the correct output for the current situation. Like *%PlayerName%* would tell the game to put the player's name in that spot of the dialogue.

The current situation changes when the player switches saved games but otherwise stays the same for awhile. At the fastest one line of dialogue will be spoken about every 1/2 second.

Which should I do? Both implementations I have come up with seem to have pros and cons.

1. Parse each line of dialogue in every file into memory and reload each one **whenever a  situation that affects output changes**.
2. Read and parse a bit of dialogue from the appropriate file **when that particular bit of dialogue is going to be said**.
3. Both are wrong and I should do something totally different. (Explain)

If I use one, won't there be at least a *small* stutter as the hard drive opens and reads 75 files at once? This feels wrong to do.

If I use two, I will be opening and closing multiple files rather rapidly for however long the user plays the game. For some reason this also feels wrong to do.

Comment: Aren't these text files based on the dialogue for a particular role of a character ? Or each file has random dialogues, for all the characters, and you select one specific one at the time of need ?

Comment: Each file contains dialogue based on a particular thing that a particular character is doing. The dialogue is randomly selected from the file.

Comment: Can all the characters do this same particular thing or only one character can do a given task and the rest are meant to do something else.

Comment: May be hybrid of 1&2. First start with 2, as new word occurs start caching, next time first check in cache before going for file.

Comment: Some can do the same thing but have different responses. Files are organized like this [Type of Character][Action Talking About].

Comment: How big are these files? Memory mapping them should boost performance significantly. Your decision tree (which character action maps to what dialog file) should be created ahead of time and cached in memory.

Comment: They are 4 to 10kb each. Really small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If occupying a bit of RAM is not a problem and the files do not contain gigabytes of dialogues, you could read in all files at the start of the application, already identifying the particular lines (i.e. make an array of all lines for fast and simple access) but with the replacing of the variables deferred until the lines are actually used in the game. Simple string substitution should not cause any noticable delay in the game.

If keeping all files in memory is not an option, you might nevertheless be able to keep a window of the next let's say three or four files, which contain the dialogues that are directly accessible from the player's current position. New files are loaded in the background as the player advances. This ensures that needed lines are always ready for immediate use, and loading a new file every some minute will not cause too much IO.

Comment: RAM wouldn't be a problem. This makes sense, too. I may do this.

Answer (score 0):

Put the stuff in a jar/zip file.  If you use the right interfaces (either class loader or your own zip manager) then the file will stay open and accesses will be reasonably efficient.